# Block IP adresses via htaccess without possible override

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I have blocked some IP addresses within the .htaccess of my webpages root like this:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
</RequireAll>
```

I also use some plugins on my webpage in sub directories, which have an own .htaccess which override the blocking entry like this:

```
<Files file.php>
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Is there any way to prevent .htaccess files in child directories to override the blocking or do I have to block the IP address in all htaccess files?

Comment: You found a solution?

Comment: Not yet, maybe I have to look for a solution at server system level

Comment: mixing 2.2 and 2.4 directives is always a bad idea. The best thing to do is to not use .htaccess at all and have everything under control in the virtualhost and specific directory directives.

Comment: "mixing 2.2 and 2.4 directives is always a bad idea." - As stated in [the Apache docs, it's "technically possible but **discouraged**"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html). The Apache 2.2 _auth_ directives will often override the Apache 2.4 directives when used in the same context, which can be unexpected and counter intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to block in every .htaccess or try to change your main/root config file.

Why not work with a whitelist(allow some hosts)?

Check this posts:

> An .htaccess file is an Apache per-directory config file. It affects the directory where the .htaccess file is located and the entire directory tree below it. Server permitting, all .htaccess files along the filesystem path (that the URL maps to) are processed, starting with the parent directory and drilling down into subdirectories. So, in your example, the .htaccess file in the "Root" will be processed before the .htaccess file in A's public_html directory - if a file below A's public_html directory is requested.

[When I have multiple .htaccess files between several sites, which is the active one?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/119843)

[.htaccess for subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805464/htaccess-for-subfolder)

[.htaccess - Rewrite multiple subdirectories to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103669/htaccess-rewrite-multiple-subdirectories-to-root)

Comment: Because I want to exclude only a few specific IPs, a whitelist doesn't work